# TypeScript type to dynamically mark certain properties of an object type as "required" and "defined"?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I've been trying to come up with generic types for a function `useDefaults` below:

```js
type ValuesOf<T extends readonly any[] | undefined> = T extends readonly any[] ? T[number] : never;
type RequiredAndDefined<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]-?: Exclude<T[P], undefined>;
};

export type EnforcedDefaultProps<P, K extends keyof P> = K extends never ? P : Omit<P, K> & RequiredAndDefined<P, K>;
export type ArrayEnforcedDefaultProps<P, K extends ReadonlyArray<keyof P> | undefined> = EnforcedDefaultProps<P, ValuesOf<K>>;

export const useDefaults = <P extends object, KEYS extends keyof P>(
    props: P | undefined,
    defaultProps: ArrayEnforcedDefaultProps<P, typeof enforcedDefaults>,
    enforcedDefaults?: ReadonlyArray<KEYS>,
): ArrayEnforcedDefaultProps<P, typeof enforcedDefaults> => {
    const newProps: P = { ...defaultProps, ...props };
    if (enforcedDefaults) { // if user explicitly passes undefined to the prop, default prop will not be used unless the key is in enforcedDefaults
        enforcedDefaults
            .filter((key) => newProps[key] === undefined)
            .forEach((key) => newProps[key] = defaultProps[key]);
    }
    return newProps as ArrayEnforcedDefaultProps<P, typeof enforcedDefaults>;
};
```

This function will do a simple assign based operation on two objects: one containing user submitted options and another containing defaults the function developer has set. It will then optionally enforce non-undefined values for certain properties (function developer provided) so that the type of the returned object of `useDefaults` shaves off the possibility that the value for each of those certain properties is `undefined`. This prevents the function developer from having to use non-null assertions, but also doesn't burden the function user.

Example desired usage:

```js
interface FormatOpts {
    maxLength?: number,
    prefix?: string,
    suffix?: string,
}

const format = (value: string, _opts?: FormatOpts) => {
    const opts = useDefaults(_opts, {
        prefix: "",
        suffix: "",
    }, ["prefix", "suffix"]);

    // prefix and suffix are guaranteed to not be `undefined` at this point, but are not explicitly required to be specified in the `_opts` object by the user of the function

    const modifiedPrefix = prefix.toUpperCase(); // want to avoid things like prefix!.toUpperCase();
}

// examples with "prefix" prop as a focus:
format("ASDF"); // OK -> prefix after useDefaults: ""
format("ASDF", { prefix: "MyPrefix" }); // OK -> prefix after useDefaults: "MyPrefix"
format("ASDF", { prefix: undefined }); // OK -> prefix after useDefaults: ""
format("ASDF", { suffix: "test" }); // OK -> prefix after useDefaults: ""
```

I'm wishing to make this as dynamic as possible (as many types inferred as possible).

While this code does compile, the typings are off somehow. Instead of having a single object type with `undefined`s removed where desired, it's a union of what looks to be each possible combination. Is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to do or to flatten these combinations down?

Screenshots have the exact types produced:

1. [One key works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TPvI.png)
2. [Two keys produce ugly union types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYoht.png)

My desired type for #2 is

```js
{
    readonly maxLength?: string | undefined;
    readonly prefix: string;
    readonly suffix: string;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite constitute a [mcve], since I imagine your issue is something like "`EnforcedDefaultProps<FormatOpts, "prefix" | "suffix">` isn't the type I expect it to be", but that isn't listed anywhere in your code, and there's a bunch of extra code obscuring the key issue.  Is it possible that you just need `type EnforcedDefaultProps<P, K extends keyof P> = [K] extends [never] ? P : Omit<P, K> & RequiredAndDefined<P, K>;`?  That is, don't [distribute the conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types) over `K`?

Comment: Thank you. After a little more experimentation, I'm now getting expect typing on at least one of my usages. Posting as answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

After reading @jcalz suggestion and doing some more experimentation/reduction, this is producing the correct typing almost dynamically:

types.ts:

```js
import { StrictOmit } from "ts-essentials";

export type RequiredAndDefined<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]-?: Exclude<T[P], undefined>;
};
export type MappedObjValue<A, B> = {
    [K in keyof A & keyof B]:
    A[K] extends B[K]
        ? never
        : K
};
export type OptionalKeys<T> = (MappedObjValue<T, Required<T>>)[keyof T];
export type KeyOrKeysOf<P> = (ReadonlyArray<keyof P>) | (keyof P);
export type ExtractArrayItem<T> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer U> ? U : T;

export type EnforcedDefaultProps<
    P extends object,
    K extends (KeyOrKeysOf<P> | undefined),
    EK = ExtractArrayItem<K>
> = [EK] extends [keyof P] ? StrictOmit<P, EK> & RequiredAndDefined<P, EK> : P;

export type EnforcedDefaultPropsInput<
    P extends object,
    K extends (KeyOrKeysOf<OP> | undefined),
    OP extends object = Pick<P, OptionalKeys<P>>,
    EK = ExtractArrayItem<K>
> = [EK] extends [keyof OP] ? EnforcedDefaultProps<OP, EK> : OP;
```

useDefaults.ts:

```js
export const useDefaults = <P extends object, ED extends Array<OptionalKeys<P>> | undefined>(
    props: P,
    defaultProps: EnforcedDefaultPropsInput<P, ED>,
    enforcedDefaults?: ED,
): EnforcedDefaultProps<P, ED> => {
    const newProps: P = { ...defaultProps, ...props };
    if (enforcedDefaults) { // if user explicitly passes undefined to the prop, default prop will not be used unless the key is in enforcedDefaults
        enforcedDefaults
            .filter((key) => newProps[key] === undefined)
            .forEach((key) => {
                newProps[key] = (defaultProps as any)[key]; // cast to any for now
            });
    }
    return newProps as EnforcedDefaultProps<P, ED>;
};
```

usage.ts:

```js
interface ISharedFormatOpts {
    prefix?: string,
    suffix?: string,
}

export interface IStringFormatOpts extends ISharedFormatOpts {
    maxLength?: number,
}

export const defaultStringFormatOpts: DeepReadonly<EnforcedDefaultPropsInput<IStringFormatOpts, "prefix" | "suffix">> = {
    prefix: "",
    suffix: "",
};

// ...

const options = useDefaults(opts as IStringFormatOpts, defaultStringFormatOpts, ["prefix", "suffix"]);
```

The resolved type of `options` is

```js
Pick<IStringFormatOpts, "maxLength"> & RequiredAndDefined<IStringFormatOpts, "prefix" | "suffix">
```

It also works correctly if object with default values is inlined which eliminates the need for the typed constant.

Comment: Cleaned up the solution a bit and created an npm package for this: [use-defaults](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-defaults).